# LuxCoreRender render times incredibly slow

Tags: luxrender-render-engine

I started a render with LuxCoreRender while ago and I'm experiencing a problem
Simply it takes 12 minutes or more just to initialize ever single frame, and if I try to stop it before the frame is initialized, blender crashes.
May it be all the volumetrics, lights or...? Seems like something is heavy but I didn't do anything different from what I did with Cycles. Any idea of what the hell is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Just figured out. LuxCoreRender doesn't like hair that much as Cycles does, so try to not increase the value too much. I also disabled my CPU and let the GPU work only and render went a bit faster tho.